# Ограничение времени на исполнение программы

Tags: linux, bash

Есть вот такой скрипт:

```
#! /bin/bash

while true; do
   camscr=(
      'ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/cam1 /web/www/preview/cam1.jpeg -y'
      'ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/cam2 /web/www/preview/cam2.jpeg -y'
      'ffmpeg -i rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/cam3 /web/www/preview/cam3.jpeg -y'
      )

   camcnt=0

   until [ $camcnt = ${#camscr[@]} ]
      do
         ${camscr[$camcnt]}
         (( camcnt++ ))
         sleep 15
      done
done
```

Для `${camscr[$camcnt]}` нужно сделать ограничение по времени работы на случай если *ffmpeg* повиснет. Кроме этих *ffmpeg* крутятся еще несколько десятков *ffmpeg*, поэтому убить все сразу их нельзя.

Я хочу поочередно запускать эти процессы либо до успешного завершения, либо с принудительным завершением через 10-15 секунд с поочередным интервалом в 15 секунд.

Comment: Можно запускать ffmpeg в фоне и затем watchdog для него, который пошлет данному процессу kill по таймауту или завершится сам при окончании данного ffmpeg

Comment: а сообщение об ошибке лучше всё же послать разработчикам *ffmpeg*. изложите то, что обнаружили: что в скрипте конструкция `timeout интервал ffmpeg параметры` не работает.

Answer (score 5):

1. можно обойтись без счётчика, перебирая непосредственно элементы массива:

   ```
   for cam in "${camscr[@]}"; do
     $cam
   done
   ```
2. можно во вложенном цикле запустить сразу все процессы (используя оператор `&`), а после цикла, подождав нужное количество секунд, «убить» все дочерние процессы:

   ```
   for cam in "${camscr[@]}"; do
     $cam &
   done
   sleep интервал
   pkill -P $$
   ```

пояснения:

- программа *pkill* обычно устанавливается вместе с базовой системой (в *debian gnu/linux* и дистрибутивах-наследниках эта программа входит в пакет *procps*).
- опция `-P идентификатор` указывает «послать сигнал всем дочерним процессам процесса с данным идентификатором». по умолчанию посылается сигнал `SIGTERM`, другой сигнал можно задать с помощью опции `-имя_или_номер` (или `--signal имя_или_номер`), например `-9` или `-KILL` или `--signal 9`.
- `$$` — в posix-совместимых оболочках эта переменная содержит идентификатор текущего процесса (т.е. процесса, выполняющего данный скрипт).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ timeout --help
Usage: timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
  or:  timeout [OPTION]
Start COMMAND, and kill it if still running after DURATION.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
      --preserve-status
                 exit with the same status as COMMAND, even when the
                   command times out
      --foreground
                 when not running timeout directly from a shell prompt,
                   allow COMMAND to read from the TTY and get TTY signals;
                   in this mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out
  -k, --kill-after=DURATION
                 also send a KILL signal if COMMAND is still running
                   this long after the initial signal was sent
  -s, --signal=SIGNAL
                 specify the signal to be sent on timeout;
                   SIGNAL may be a name like 'HUP' or a number;
                   see 'kill -l' for a list of signals
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

DURATION is a floating point number with an optional suffix:
's' for seconds (the default), 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for days.

If the command times out, and --preserve-status is not set, then exit with
status 124.  Otherwise, exit with the status of COMMAND.  If no signal
is specified, send the TERM signal upon timeout.  The TERM signal kills
any process that does not block or catch that signal.  It may be necessary
to use the KILL (9) signal, since this signal cannot be caught, in which
case the exit status is 128+9 rather than 124.

GNU coreutils online help: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/>
Full documentation at: <http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/timeout>
or available locally via: info '(coreutils) timeout invocation'
```

Comment: пожалуйста, приведите пример использования

Comment: кстати, под вопросом была длинная дискуссия именно с обсуждением запуска `timeout интервал ffmpeg параметры`. так вот у автора вопроса **внутри скрипта** это не работало. от дискуссии остался [только мой финальный комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668965/#comment970850_668965).